# How does SqlDataReader receive the data?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sqldatareader

The following simple code retrieve data with SqlDataReader:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name] FROM [Persons] AS [t0]";
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rdr["id"] + " " + rdr["name"]);
    }
```

While the code is running, I use Sql Profiler to monitor the DB. And I saw only one select command.

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name] FROM [Persons] AS [t0]
```

So it seems the SqlDataReader will retrieve **ALL** the data from server first, and then enumerate them.

Is that true? What if the data is too many?

Comment: I tested where I started a reader and changed the next row but the reader did not get the revised value.  So it seems to read ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SqlDataReader has a 8 kilobytes buffer.

Duplicate question: [How DataReader works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383920/how-datareader-works)