# Comparing ways to Treat SqlDataReader Returned values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

which of the following ways for reading and using SqlDataReader returned records are better?

1 -using data directly:

```
<table>
<%while(Reader.Read()){%>
<tr>
    <td><%Reader.GetInt32(0)%></td>
    <td><%Reader.GetString(1)%></td>
    <td><%Reader.GetBoolean(2)%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
```

2-reading records to a list of structure and closing connection as soon as possible and then using the read data:

```
<%struct Data{
public int id;
public string name;
public bool active;
}
List<Data> Datas = new List<Data>();
    while(Reader.Read()){
    Datas.Add(new Data(){
        id = Reader.GetInt32(0),
        name = Reader.GetString(1),
        active = Reader.GetBoolean(2)
    }
}
connection.Close();%>
    <table>
<%for(int i=0;i<Datas.Length;i++){%>
    <tr>
        <td><%Datas[i].id%></td>
        <td><%=Datas[i].name%></td>
        <td<%=Datas[i].active%></td>
    </tr>
   <% } %>
    </table>
```

Comment: Better in what way? In terms of how long you're keeping a connection open, separating UI and data access concerns, performance, readability, ...?

Comment: @MichaelPetito My main concern is performance, and then the time connection stays open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question (and comment) suggest that you're trying to optimize performance, but this is probably the least distinguishing aspect of the two samples you've provided.

I doubt that either approach is going to show an appreciable performance gain, especially since [SqlDataReader is buffering your results anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383920/how-datareader-works).  That said, you may encounter two situations where this isn't quite true:

- Iterating over many thousands of records, in which case you may be able to send some results to the client faster in a streaming approach like #1.
- Performing substantial work for each record, in which case you may be able to close your connection faster in a buffered approach like #2.

What you should consider instead is which approach has better design characteristics while still providing acceptable performance.  In that case, the thought process behind approach #2 definitely has advantages.  Separating data access concerns (retrieving a list of `Data`) from presentation concerns (displaying a list of `Data`) [makes your code more maintainable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

If you need to, you can still achieve the streaming characteristics of approach #1 by having your data access layer return a streaming `IEnumerable<Data>` instead of `List<Data>`.