# How to change buffer size of SqlDataReader in C#?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am using `SqlDataReader` for data migration. How can I increase the number of records inserting to the destination at a time?

Comment: but... sqldatareader doesn't *do* inserting... so: what *are* you using for the insert? if it is something like sqlbulkcopy, then *that* has multiple ways of tweaking the batch size (which is: the buffer size) - most importantly `.BatchSize`

Comment: to be honest I don't understand, what you want :-|

Comment: I reckon OP means he wants to increase the buffer used to "insert" the records to the destination(database=source, client=destination), so to read the records. I'm not sure but i think that depends on the network buffer which you can't change programmatically and on the database drivers([usually 8kilobytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383961/284240)).

Comment: Actual requirement is to migrate data from sql server to postgres.Code read data from source using sqldatareader and using npgsql insert data into the destination.its known that by default sqldatareader can hold 8kb data at a time(not sure).i want to know howmuch data sqldatareader can handle at a time and is it possible to increase...

Comment: @saju do you have any reason for wishing to do so? Usually, any reader is going to out-perform any writer, so it is very unlikely you would have an empty buffer. What makes you think it would be useful to increase this? What to you expect to achieve by doing do?

Comment: i have to migrate a 140 Gb DB.Now it tooks 64 hours for migration.i want to reduce this.for migrating tables with text column also took more time.

Comment: The network buffers are almost certainly not your bottleneck. The way you do your copying *is*. For large data transfers like this, look at things like parallel inserts, bulk/batch copying, table locking and running clients locally on the machine. If you want to process more rows at a time, you can: just buffer them yourself. This is irrespective of the size of the network buffers used. If you've optimized *everything else*, you can use the `packet size` option of the SQL connection string to use larger packets (up to 32767 bytes), but don't expect miracles from that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to increase the number of records inserting to the destination at a time.

Then this is unrelated to `SqlDataReader`, and you'll need to look at whatever tool you're using for the insert. If you're using `SqlBulkCopy`, then this should be as simple as changing the `.BatchSize`. If you're using other mechanisms, you'll have to be specific. For example, if you're using an SP to do the inserts that only handles one row at a time, one option might be to use MARS and overlapping `async` operations; I have a utility method that I use for this type of sequential fixed-depth overlapping (which is *very* different to what `Parallel.ForEach` would do, for example, even with a fixed max-DOP). If you're using an insert that works via TDS-based table-parameters, then: just buffer that much data locally before calling the operation. If you're using an ORM such as EF: refer to the ORM's insert documentation.

But: to emphasize: the one thing that *doesn't* get a vote on this is: the data-reader.

Comment: Actual requirement is to migrate data from sql server to postgres.Code read data from source using sqldatareader and using npgsql insert data into the destination.its known that by default sqldatareader can hold 8kb data at a time(not sure).i want to know howmuch data sqldatareader can handle at a time and is it possible to increase...All done in a single server ,not in network.